# How to match 2 columns, then take a value from a third column and sum them up

Tags: excel

I have an excel spreadsheet.  I need to match data in 2 columns and if those match, take a number from column 3 and put it in column 4.

Ex: Column A has multiple names: (Steve, Josh, John), column B has one name (Steve), column 3 has a number (546).  I need to match Column A to Column B, then take the number from Column C (that corresponds to Column B) and put that number into column D.  If column A has multiple matches, then I need column D to be a sum of the numbers from column C.

I've tried vlookup and a few different things but am stumped on how to get them to sum the values from column C.

See screenshot below for my example.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKJOg.png)

Comment: Sounds like you want SUMIF or SUMIFS.

Comment: I don't think I explained it enough.  Column A, row 1 has multiple names (steve, josh, john), then column B has one name  (steve), column C has a number (546).  I need to search column B and match the names to column A and then add up all matched names with the numbers from C.  will SumIFS work for that?  This is my first time trying to figure this out.

Comment: It would be easier if you mocked the data and expected outcome in the question instead of trying to explain it.

Comment: Are you saying anytime any of the names in Column A are present in Column B, you need to sum the number? If so, I think a helper column might be necessary.

Comment: Ok I added a Screenshot so you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: how big is your true data set in reality?

Comment: column A is 97 rows, column b is 435 rows, column c is 435 rows.  not huge.  i can do it manually but it will take me awhile and this will be ongoing. Is it a problem that I use a ; instead of a ,?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMIF() with wild cards:

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"*" & B1 & "*",C:C)
```

[image]